# Map Kit Location Images

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am using Map kit to display a bunch of locations and data related to it.
When I use Apple Maps I can see that locations have related images provided by Yelp.

Does map kit provide a way to access those images? Is there any way to obtain images from a respective location??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those images are not part of the SDK and you can't use them within your app directly, but you can use Yelp API to get business information, including images. Check https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business for more information.